# Is there a way to configure my dock so that it stores multiple rows of icons (instead of placing them all side by side)?

Tags: 22.04, icons, unity-dash, dock, favorites

In Windows 10, my taskbar is only one row high but stores three different rows of pinned icons. I can access different rows by using a set of arrow keys at the right of the taskbar. Conveniently, I can also temporarily expand the taskbar to three rows in height, which makes it easier to rearrange icons across rows.

In Ubuntu, I have my dock/dash/favorites bar pinned to the bottom of the screen, but it only takes up a single row. When I have too many icons pinned to it, I have to drag my mouse to the left or to the right to access icons at the edge of the dock.

Is there a way to add in arrow keys and a multi-row setup so that it's more like the Windows interface? I would find this more convenient than having to scroll horizontally in order to access icons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is not possible. Clicking the "Application overview" on the dock will take you to the Application overview. A shortcut key, <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, will do the same. With one click away, you have plenty of room to arrange your icons to launch applications in multiple rows and, if needed, groups and multiple screens.

A user typically uses about 5 - 8 applications very frequently. Put these on the dock. The others are in easy reach one click away, leaving you more room for your actual work.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and for suggesting a solid alternative.